# Jquery подправить функцию визуального редактора.

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg

Есть редактор Imperavi. Есть у него функция, которая должна удалять столбец из таблиц. Она не работает: при вызове этой функции пишется вот что (в файербаге) 
`    
TypeError: $current_td.get(...) is undefined

var index = $current_td.get(0).cellIndex;

А вот и сама функция:

```
     tableDeleteColumn: function()

       {
        var $table = $(this.getParent()).closest('table');
        if (!this.isParentRedactor($table)) return false;
        if ($table.size() == 0) return false;

        this.bufferSet();

        var $current_td =  $(this.getParent()).closest('td');
        var index = $current_td.get(0).cellIndex;

        // Set the focus correctly
        $table.find('tr').each($.proxy(function(i, elem)
        {
            var focusIndex = index - 1 < 0 ? index + 1 : index - 1;
            if (i === 0)
            {
                $(elem).find('td').eq(focusIndex).prepend('<span id="selection-marker-1">' + this.opts.invisibleSpace + '</span>');
            }

            $(elem).find('td').eq(index).remove();

        }, this));

        this.selectionRestore();
        this.sync();
    },
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что с ней не так?

Comment: у них на сайте всё работает, сделайте пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: У них на сайте тоже это не работает. Попробуйте создать стандартную таблицу (2 строки и 3 колонки) и удалить из нее столбец, выбрав из выпадающего меню "Delete Column"

Comment: получилось, браузер chrome.

Comment: В хроме тоже получилось, но в мозилле проблему с этим хотелось бы исправить.